# Можно ли создать триггер на представление?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Можно ли создать триггер на представление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, для `view` возможно использование триггеров.

Есть несколько ограничений, [указанных в мануале](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html) ([ну и в коде](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/commands/trigger.c#L261)):

- триггер не может быть для действия `truncate`
- для `for each row` триггеров возможно использовать только `instead of` триггеры.